# Wrapping text next to image in while

Tags: php, css

I am trying to fix the way my search function displays its results. I'll attach the code and then I'll fill you in with the rest of the details. This is the php and html part:

```
$counter = 0; 
echo "<div class='box_afisare'>";
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $resulta )) 
    {   $poza=$result['id_oferta'];
        $p="SELECT * FROM poza where id='".$poza."'";
        $rez2 = mysql_query($p); 
        ++$counter;
        $modulo = $counter % 2;
        ?>
        <div class="border">
        <!-- DE MODIFICAT LOCALHOST -->
        <img  src="http://localhost/design/photo/images/<?php echo $poza ;?>/1-mini.jpg" id="poza"  />
        <?php
        echo "<div class='aranjare_text'>";
        echo "<a href='oferta.php?id={$result['id_oferta']}'><h3>{$result['denumire_locatie']} - {$result['tip_locatie']}</h3></a>";
        echo "<p>{$result['judet']}, {$result['localitate']}</p>";
        echo "</br>";
        echo "</br>";
        echo "<a href='oferta.php?id={$result['id_oferta']}'><p>Vizualizeaza</p></a>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";

        if ($modulo < 1) 
        {
            echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
        }

    }

    echo "</div>";
```

Here is the CSS for the divs in the while loop:

```
.clear
{
    clear:both;
}

.aranjare_text
{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 35%;
}

.border
{
    width: 47%;
    float:left;
}
```

Everything you see up there is contained in the following divs as well:

```
#wrapper{width:1080px; margin:0 auto;}
.box_afisare
{
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #999999; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color:white;
    height:100%
}
```

Now that we're done with the code, what I want is to display the h3 and the two paragraphs next to the image. Thing is the first query result looks as I would like it to but the others are not arranged properly. It's a mess actually. I guess that it might be that clear's fault. This is where I want you to help. I also have a problem when showing an uneven no. of queries, .box_afisare won't contain the last one as well. Thanks and let me know if I need to edit my post before downrating. I'm kinda new to all this.

This is the HTML generated code:

```
<div class='box_afisare'>           <div class="border">
            <!-- DE MODIFICAT LOCALHOST -->
            <img  src="http://localhost/design/photo/images/52042156c65d4/1-mini.jpg" id="poza"  />
            <div class='aranjare_text'><a href='oferta.php?id=52042156c65d4'><h3>Test - Club</h3></a><p>Bistrita-Nasaud, Oarecare</p></br></br><a href='oferta.php?id=52042156c65d4'><p>Vizualizeaza</p></a></div></div>            <div class="border">
            <!-- DE MODIFICAT LOCALHOST -->
            <img  src="http://localhost/design/photo/images/5205147a5f958/1-mini.jpg" id="poza"  />
            <div class='aranjare_text'><a href='oferta.php?id=5205147a5f958'><h3>test555555 - Restaurant</h3></a><p>Arges, grqw</p></br></br><a href='oferta.php?id=5205147a5f958'><p>Vizualizeaza</p></a></div></div><div class='clear'></div>         <div class="border">
            <!-- DE MODIFICAT LOCALHOST -->
            <img  src="http://localhost/design/photo/images/5205148d1aeb6/1-mini.jpg" id="poza"  />
            <div class='aranjare_text'><a href='oferta.php?id=5205148d1aeb6'><h3>test555555 - Restaurant</h3></a><p>Arges, grqw</p></br></br><a href='oferta.php?id=5205148d1aeb6'><p>Vizualizeaza</p></a></div></div>          <div class="border">
            <!-- DE MODIFICAT LOCALHOST -->
            <img  src="http://localhost/design/photo/images/5205326cf08ae/1-mini.jpg" id="poza"  />
            <div class='aranjare_text'><a href='oferta.php?id=5205326cf08ae'><h3>testnou - Restaurant</h3></a><p>Alba, vsfasf</p></br></br><a href='oferta.php?id=5205326cf08ae'><p>Vizualizeaza</p></a></div></div><div class='clear'></div>           <div class="border">
            <!-- DE MODIFICAT LOCALHOST -->
            <img  src="http://localhost/design/photo/images/5206337cd1cef/1-mini.jpg" id="poza"  />
            <div class='aranjare_text'><a href='oferta.php?id=5206337cd1cef'><h3>Test - Restaurant</h3></a><p>Alba, loc</p></br></br><a href='oferta.php?id=5206337cd1cef'><p>Vizualizeaza</p></a></div></div>          <div class="border">
            <!-- DE MODIFICAT LOCALHOST -->
            <img  src="http://localhost/design/photo/images/520777317270e/1-mini.jpg" id="poza"  />
            <div class='aranjare_text'><a href='oferta.php?id=520777317270e'><h3>sdasda - Restaurant</h3></a><p>Alba, dasdsadsa</p></br></br><a href='oferta.php?id=520777317270e'><p>Vizualizeaza</p></a></div></div><div class='clear'></div></div>
```

Sorry but it's not formated.

Comment: Hello, I'm not reading whole article. But just to point you: mysql_* is deprecated! use mysqli instead for example. dont use fetch_array if not needed, use fetch_assoc instead. U're calling <?php tags wrongly - it could be the way you're doing, php will let you write almost anything, but this is not right way closing php tag in while cycle and opening new php tag - doesnt make sence.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, now I clearly see that I could haved used just one opening and one closing php tags. I'll start using mysqli in my next project since you're not the first one that told me to start using it. Thanks again!

Comment: Post the generated HTML instead of PHP code.

Comment: I've posted the generated HTML. I hope you can decipher it. Don't mind the comments, it was actually a comment that I placed in the loop.

Comment: Is this the layout you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/tH8pW/

Comment: Not exactly but yeah, nearly. The only exception is that I want two articles on the same row delimited by a margin.

Comment: @hungerstar I've added a simple float:left; to the aranjare_text class and your style sheet now works like charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try putting your image in the same div as the text, right before the text, and give it

```
<img align='left' src=...
```

Comment: Ok. I did that and it doesn't display the pictures anymore. Besides the text is shown in the exactly same messy way as before. Usign the align attribute isn't considered to be bad practice? Thanks anyway!

Comment: It is equivalent I believe to wrapping it in a div and floating it, I use it when I think it is more convenient than floating like if I am not using any divs. Not sure why it would make the image disappear outright though.

Comment: No idea but probably in my case the clear is the problem. I just can't figure out another way of doing things since I need two entries on same row.

Comment: @SporeDev do not use the `align` attribute, it is depreciated.  Target the image with CSS and a possible CSS Class.